# Mixing and WasapiOut

Tags: naudio

I am trying to create a low latency playback of data received over a network. Due to the requirement of low latency, I selected WasapiOut (have tried both shared/exclusive, using/not using event sync, 25 or 50 ms). I have a MixingSampleProvider (IEEE, 44.1 kHz, tried with one or two channels) feeding into the WasapiOut as I will have several streams to play.

If I use shared access, I get an exception from HRESULT 0x88890003, if I use exclusive access, I get "Can't find a supported format to use".

I based this on the NAudioDemo app, the Audio Playback Demo. It seems to me the only difference is that I want a mixer in the chain. Is that not possible?

```
var waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100, 1);
this.mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(waveFormat)
{
   ReadFully = true
};

try
{
   using (this.audioOut = new WasapiOut(selectedDevice, AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive, false, 25))
   {
      this.audioOut.Init(this.mixer);
      this.audioOut.Play();
   }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e);
   throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because it is mono. Try supplying a stereo source and I expect that will work